# Jenkins tomcat7 deploying error

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins

I have a jenkins job named 'SampleMavenDeploy1' which copies artifacts(war file,pom.xml) from upstream project('SampleMavenBuild1') successfully to this project.

I have following configuration for this project:

"

Build Steps:

```
Copy artifacts from another project
    Project Name:SampleMavenBuild1
```

Post-build Actions:

```
War/Ear files:MavenWebAppV14/target/*.war

Context Path:webapps

Containers:
    Tomcat7.x
        Manager username:tomcat
        Manager Password:tomcat
        Tomcat Url:http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

"

The build of SampleMavenBuild1(make war file of a maven project) has succeeded. In workspace of this job (SampleMavenDeploy1), there is war file (MavenWebAppV14/target/MavenWebAppV14.war). I have also configured tomcat-users.xml to add user of username 'tomcat' , password 'tomcat' and roles as 'manager-gui' and 'manager-script' .

I am facing following errors in a jenkins build of a job. This job is designed for deploying war file on tomcat7 via CI server. I have also 'deploy to tomcat' plugin installed in jenkins.

Started by user vikas

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\vikachou\.jenkins\jobs\SampleMavenDeploy1\workspace
Copied 2 artifacts from "SampleMavenBuild1" build number 4
Deploying C:\Users\vikachou\.jenkins\jobs\SampleMavenDeploy1\workspace\MavenWebAppV14\target\MavenWebAppV14.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [C:\Users\vikachou\.jenkins\jobs\SampleMavenDeploy1\workspace\MavenWebAppV14\target\MavenWebAppV14.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:189)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:918)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:896)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1770)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unknown command /manager/text/list

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
    ... 16 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unknown command /manager/text/list

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:918)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:896)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1770)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anyone who can figure out is most welcomed . 
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give permissions to the text-manager to be able to deploy.

Just go to tomcat-users.xml and add this:

```
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Or just give the `manager-script` permission to your existing tomcat-manager user

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the base URL to localhost:8080/ in the deploy URL, not the manager URL which is localhost:8080/manager/text (which is what happened in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. But I had the tomcat users refresh like the first answer of this question and the problem still persists on Jenkins.

When I tried to connect to tomcat admin zone using my navigator, tomcat didn't display the page to me, because the tomcat-admin package was not installed. So I've installed the `tomcat7-admin` package and restarted tomcat :

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-admin
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Then the problem was fixed. It was because Jenkins couldn't connect with the program. So easy!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the users and and assign the manager-gui (for GUI access) and manager-script (for access like Jenkins deployment ). Also, make sure to edit the file /webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml, either to comment out valve or define appropriate reg ex for allow attribute

Answer (score -2):

If it shows a connection error or fails to load when you deploy jenkins.war file on tomcat, then follow the steps below.

1. Paste the jenkins folder inside tomcat/webapps.
2. Restart the tomcat (localhost or ip:8080/jenkins)
3. Jenkins will load and may asks for password.
4. To get the jenkins admin password then run 
   `{cat /opt/tomcat/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword}`
5. If the permission is denied to access the password then 
   `sudo chmod 0777 /opt/tomcat/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`
   or else run `ls -a` there you will see .jenkins folder.