# Deploy war file to Tomcat 8x

Tags: jenkins, tomcat

[image]I am trying to Deploy the war file to Tomcat server 8x.

Build it getting success but not able to deploy getting the attached error.

Comment: Please check if this SO helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235245/jenkins-tomcat7-deploying-error

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I tried but still no luck.       <user username="deployer" password="deployer" roles="manager-script, manager-gui"/>